# Plucking an inner most item by its index with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get better at understanding list comprehension, and I started this thing with a list of tuples that I've cast to a list of lists.

With list comprehension, how can I pluck out from the inner most list's index that contains a `2` in the last index?

```
results = [
  [
    [529L, u'wat', u'wat', 3L, 2], [530L, u'wat', u'wat', 3L, 1], [531L, u'wat', u'wat', 3L, 1]
  ], [
    [533L, u'weeeee', u'weeeee', 3L, 1], [534L, u'weeeee', u'weeeee', 3L, 1]
  ]
]
```

Would be:

```
results = [
  [
    [530L, u'wat', u'wat', 3L, 1], [531L, u'wat', u'wat', 3L, 1]
  ], [
    [533L, u'weeeee', u'weeeee', 3L, 1], [534L, u'weeeee', u'weeeee', 3L, 1]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can't see how your input corresponds to your output? Is it *How do I remove the first element in a list of lists that contains `2` as its last element*? Or do you want to remove all elements in each last where its last element is 2, or...?

Comment: @JonClements I think it is remove all inner lists with a `2` in the last index.

Comment: If you just write it out in a ```for``` loop, you'll be able to see the process then it might be easier to *work backward*  and convert it to a list comprehension - try it, it will be fun.  I like to use [```operator.itemgetter```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) when plucking out items of a sequence for comparison: ```last_item = operator.itemgetter(-1); if not last_item(thing) == 2```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = [[x for x in lst if x[-1]!=2] for lst in results]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
results_not_ending_in_2 = [
    [inner_list for inner_list in outer_list if inner_list[-1] != 2]
    for outer_list in results
]
```